# How do i get python to match sounds for me, is it possible?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudioanalysis

For quite the while now i've been trying to find a way to make python listen to my background pc sounds or to sounds an app makes and if it notices a sound which is simular or the same as an mp3 file i provide to the program it will give me an output of some sort.

Example:

I get a ping on discord

Python notices somehow, and goes

```
    ping=0
    if ping.detected:
        ping = ping+1
    print(ping)
```

and the output will be 1

Im pretty new to python with only 3 years of messing around with like a 2 year break in between where i didn't do anything even close to programing so i don't know if it exists in some other form or if it's even solveble with python.

I tried using py audio and wave but i didn't quite have enought brain capacity to make it work.

Comment: This may be interesting https://willdrevo.com/fingerprinting-and-audio-recognition-with-python/

Comment: What's your actual use-case? If all you're trying to do is to write a script that reacts to Discord messages, you're better off using the official Discord API.